# Center the horizontal scroll bar of my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollbar

I wonder if it is possible to center the horizontal scroll bar of my site using JavaScript or jQuery. 
A scroll bar appears for users who use resolutions like 1024 x 768, and therefore, would like her position always stay in the center.

Example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YK8Xe.png

Comment: Even if you could, I don't think it would be good practice. If you don't want part of your site hidden for specific screen resolutions, you should make the site responsive.
But if you really want to do this, you could add `margin: 0 auto` to center the page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given that the scrollable element in question is `document.body` you could use the following JavaScript to centre the horizontal scrollbar:

```
document.body.scrollLeft = (document.body.scrollWidth - document.body.clientWidth) / 2
```